# Regex for simple matching

Tags: iphone, ios, regex, ipad

I need to write a regex for matching a pattern.

Pattern to match is:

```
[#ABC...Z0-9].
```

anybody?

Comment: If you had googled 'iOS regular expression', one of the first links would have pointed to Apple's official documentation of `NSRegularExpression`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [`NSRegularExpression`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Your code can be like this:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = 
    [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[#ABC...Z0-9]" 
                         options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                         error:nil];
```

and for substring between `[#` and `]` try this regex:

```
\[#[^\]]+\]
```

explain:

> ***`[character_group]`*** Negation: Matches any single character that is not in `character_group`
>
> ***`+`*** Matches the previous element one or more times.
>
> ***`\[`*** Matches `[` charachter

Comment: what I am trying to do is get the substring between "[#" and "]"